# How to format the spaces in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a below file

```
ABCD|12345|N|YES  
ABCDEFGH|12344444|NO|YES  
AB|12|N|Y
```

I want the output as below

```
ABCD                12345      N   YES  
ABCDEFGH            123444444  NO  YES  
AB                  12         N   Y
```

Basically need to format this in a good readable format. Like a table. (Here spaces are not exactly coming as I want)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` and `column -t`:

```
tr '|' '\t' < file | column -t
ABCD      12345     N   YES
ABCDEFGH  12344444  NO  YES
AB        12        N   Y
```

`tr` is to replace `|` by a tab and `column -t` is for producing tabular formatted output.

Comment: column is not working.. :(  ERROR ::    ksh: column:  not found.

Comment: What OS you ore on? `column` is a standard unix utility.

Comment: benappl:BRPA$ uname -a
AIX                            Is there anyother way I can do this ? It would be really helpfull

Comment: Are there 4 columns always in each row?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
echo "ABCD|12345|N|YES ABCDEFGH|12344444|NO|YES AB|12|N|Y" | sed 's/|/ /g'
```

This sed will search for "|" and would replace with space in entire line. Or you could use tr command like:

```
echo "ABCD|12345|N|YES ABCDEFGH|12344444|NO|YES AB|12|N|Y" | tr '|' ' '
```

to translate from pipe "|" to space.

Comment: Yes sed and tr can modify the pipe.. but im not getting it in the correct format as i need